# Is ROS Answers an Alternative to the [ros-users] Mailing List?

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a meta-question, but is **ROS Answers** an alternative to the [ros-users] mailing list?
The search, tagging and editing facilities cerainly make **ROS Answers** a better medium.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9060/is-ros-answers-an-alternative-to-the-%5Bros-users%5D-mailing-list?/) by [Adi Shavit](https://answers.ros.org/users/24/adi-shavit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-15**:
FYI to those who don't monitor ros-developers here is the thread where the creation of this service was discussed: https://code.ros.org/lurker/thread/20110208.182812.07530210.en.html#i20110208.182812.07530210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question might be a duplicate of [this one.](http://answers.ros.org/question/10/when-should-one-use-answersrosorg-vs-the-ros-users)

But generally, to summarize, ROS Answers provides an alternative to the mailing list in that it serves as a cache to commonly asked questions that is easily searchable for people just joining the community.

It is intended to reduce the volume of the traffic on ros-users (which has swelled in the past couple months).

Also, the goal is to get users and developers alike on here, so your question is just as likely to be answered on here as it would be on the mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3